# SQLite - Selecting records that don't have a counterpart in another table

Tags: sqlite, select

I have 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE People(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    'First Name' text,
    'Last Name' text,
);

CREATE TABLE Courses(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    'Course Name' text,
    'Course Refresh Rate' integer
);

CREATE TABLE [Course Enrolment](
    'Person ID' integer,
    'Course ID' integer,
    FOREIGN KEY ('Person ID') REFERENCES People(id),
    FOREIGN KEY ('Course ID') REFERENCES Courses(id)
);

CREATE TABLE [Course Participation](
    'Person ID' integer,
    'Course ID' integer,
    'Date Taken' text,
    FOREIGN KEY ('Person ID') REFERENCES People(id),
    FOREIGN KEY ('Course ID') REFERENCES Courses(id)
);
```

I am trying to select People who are enrolled for a course, but have either never taken the course (and therefore don't have a record in the Course Participation table) or have taken the course more than 'Course Refresh Rate' years ago. I have written a select statement, but it is not working as intended.

```
SELECT [First Name],
       [Last Name]
  FROM people AS p
       LEFT JOIN courses AS c
       JOIN [course enrolment] AS ce
       JOIN [course participation] AS cp
        ON p.id = ce.[Person ID] 
        AND p.id = cp.[Person ID] 
        AND c.id = ce.[Course ID] 
        AND c.id = cp.[Course ID]
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Course Enrolment] as ce_2 WHERE ce_2.[Person ID] = p.id and ce_2.[Course ID] = c.id )
    AND ([date taken] < date( 'now', '-' || [course refresh rate] || ' year' )
    or NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Course Participation] WHERE cp.[Person ID] = p.id and cp.[Course ID] = c.id ))
;
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: A misunderstanding of the Exists statement, I have replaced it with what I believe is the correct syntax.

Comment: I think the problem might be that with your `JOIN ... ON ...` construct, you are building a table that **only** contains people that have an entry in **each** of your tables. Try leaving away the ON statement as a whole, and select the unique results afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, Jan - How would I go about selecting the unique results afterwards? I'm quite new to SQL, and can't think of another way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id,
                p.[First Name],
                p.[Last Name]
FROM People AS p
JOIN [Course Enrolment] AS ce ON p.id = ce.[Person ID]
JOIN Courses AS c ON ce.[Course ID] = c.id
LEFT JOIN [Course Participation] AS cp ON cp.[Person ID] = p.id AND
                                          cp.[Course ID] = c.id
WHERE cp.[Date Taken] IS NULL
   OR cp.[Date Taken] < date('now', '-' || c.[Course Refresh Rate] || ' year')
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the response. All that I had to add was a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

How about filtering the recent participants from all others like this :-

```
SELECT [First Name],
       [Last Name]
  FROM people AS p
  JOIN courses AS c
  JOIN [course enrolment] AS ce
    ON p.id = ce.[Person ID] 
   AND c.id = ce.[Course ID] 

MINUS

SELECT [First Name],
       [Last Name]
  FROM people AS p
  JOIN courses AS c
  JOIN [course enrolment] AS ce
  JOIN [course participation] AS cp
    ON p.id = ce.[Person ID] 
   AND p.id = cp.[Person ID] 
   AND c.id = ce.[Course ID] 
   AND c.id = cp.[Course ID] 
 WHERE [date taken] > date( 'now', '-' || [course refresh rate] || ' year')
```

**NOT TESTED**

Comment: I agree with the logic here, and thank you for the response - however when testing I received an error.